# Items are added in RecyclerView but not visible

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm retrieving list of few users which being added and but are not visible. When I added Toast on item click it shows data **null** and android studio give warning  also in model class the **constructor is never used** .I'm using `ChildEventListener` and a custom adapter

> Custom adapter code

```
class CustomMemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetMeeting_2.User_MemberHolder>{

    List<UserModel_member_DP_NAME> mList;

    CustomMemberAdapter(List<UserModel_member_DP_NAME> mList) {
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    @Override
    public User_MemberHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.set_meeting_userlist_item,parent,false);
        return new User_MemberHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(User_MemberHolder holder, int position) {
        final UserModel_member_DP_NAME model = mList.get(position);
        holder.txt.setText(model.getName());
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(model.getDp()).into(holder.img);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), String.valueOf(model.getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

> Model Class code

```
private static class UserModel_member_DP_NAME {
    String dp,name;
    UserModel_member_DP_NAME(){}

    UserModel_member_DP_NAME(String dp, String name) { //never used warning
        this.dp = dp;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDp() {
        return dp;
    }
    public void setDp(String dp) {
        this.dp = dp;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

> ChildEventListener code

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    defaultQuery = mDatabase.child("users").child(current_user).child("directorylist");
    defaultQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            UserModel_member_DP_NAME model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel_member_DP_NAME.class);
            memberList.add(model);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> here is my database structure[image]

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the adapter? Probably you should first set the adapter with the list then update it and then notify data set change. Did you check if your list has data? Put a break point in onChildAdded and see if its getting invoked?

Comment: never mind solved it. i needed to get each key in onChildAdded and then inside it a valueEventListener for retrieving data...i was querying name and DP in directorylist instead of users